# TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined Socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I built a chat app using react, node & socket.io
Three of the components involved are

1. SocketProvider.js - context API which manages socket.
2. ConversationProvider.js - context API which manages chat conversations
3. Openconversation.js - A single conversation UI component with message box, Uploadimage UI Component, send button & conversation messages.
4. UploadImage.js - A UI component with input type file field & Imgur API to upload selected image to imgur & return the URL of uploaded image.

Below is code for all the three components.

**SocketProvider.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import { useContacts } from './ContactsProvider';

const SocketContext = React.createContext();


export function useSocket() {
    return useContext(SocketContext)
}

export function SocketProvider({id,children}) {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState();
    const {contacts} = useContacts();
    const stringContacts =  JSON.stringify(contacts);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const newSocket = io(
            'http://192.168.0.113:5000',
            {transports: ['websocket'],query: {id,stringContacts}}, 
        )
        setSocket(newSocket)

        return () => newSocket.close()
    }, [id,stringContacts] )

    return (
        <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
            {children}
        </SocketContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Conversationprovider.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage';
import { useContacts } from '../contexts/ContactsProvider'
import { useSocket } from './SocketProvider';

const ConversationsContext = React.createContext();

export function useConversations() {
    return useContext(ConversationsContext)
}

export function ConversationsProvider({ children, id }) {
    const [conversations, setConversations] = useLocalStorage('conversations', [])
    const { contacts } = useContacts();
    const socket = useSocket();
    const [selectedConversationIndex, setSelectedConversationIndex] = useState(0);

    const addMessageToConversation = useCallback(({ recipients, text, sender }) => {
        setConversations(prevConversations => {
            let madeChanges = false;
            const newMessage = { sender, text }
            const newConversations = prevConversations.map(conversation => {
                if (arrayEquality(conversation.recipients, recipients)) {
                    madeChanges = true;
                    return { ...conversation, messages: [...conversation.messages, newMessage] }
                }

                return conversation
            })

            if (madeChanges) {
                return newConversations
            }

            else {
                return [...prevConversations, { recipients, messages: [newMessage] }]
            }
        })


    }, [setConversations])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(socket == null) return
        
        socket.on('recieve-message', addMessageToConversation)
        return () => socket.off('recieve-message')
    }, [socket,addMessageToConversation])

    function sendMessage(recipients, text) {
        socket.emit('send-message', {recipients, text})
        addMessageToConversation({ recipients, text, sender: id })
    }

    

    function createConversations(recipients) {
        setConversations(prevConversations => {
            return [...prevConversations, { recipients, messages: [] }]
        })
    }

    const formattedConversations = conversations.map((conversation, index) => {
        const recipients = conversation.recipients.map(recipient => {
            const contact = contacts.find(contact => {
                return contact.id === recipient
            })
            const name = (contact && contact.name) || recipient;
            return { id: recipient, name }
        })
        const messages = conversation.messages.map(message => {
            const contact = contacts.find(contact => {
                return contact.id === message.sender
            })
            const name = (contact && contact.name) || message.sender;
            const fromMe = id === message.sender;
            return { ...message, senderName: name, fromMe }

        })
        const selected = selectedConversationIndex === index
        return { ...conversation, recipients, selected, messages }
    })

    const value = {
        formattedConversations,
        selectedConversation: formattedConversations[selectedConversationIndex],
        sendMessage,
        conversationSelected: setSelectedConversationIndex,
        createConversations
    }

    return (
        <ConversationsContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </ConversationsContext.Provider>
    )
}

function arrayEquality(a, b) {
    if (a.length != b.length) return false

    a.sort()
    b.sort()

    return a.every((element, index) => {
        return element === b[index]
    })
}
```

**Openconversation.js**

```
import { Button, Form, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useConversations } from '../contexts/ConversationsProvider';
import Uploadimage from './UploadImage';

export default function OpenConversation() {
    const [text, setText] = useState('');
    const [url,setUrl] = useState('');
    const setRef = useCallback((node) => {
        if(node) {
            node.scrollIntoView({smooth: true})
        }
    }, []);
    const { sendMessage, selectedConversation } = useConversations()

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
         sendMessage(selectedConversation.recipients.map(recipient => {
            return recipient.id;
        }), text)
        setText('')
    }

    function sendImage(image) {
        **sendMessage(selectedConversation.recipients.map(recipient => {
            return recipient.id;
            }), image)** 
    }


    

    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">
            <div className="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto ">
                <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start justify-content-end px-3" style={{'minHeight': '100%'}}>
                    {selectedConversation.messages.map((message, index) => {
                        const lastMessage = selectedConversation.messages.length - 1 === index; 
                        return <div ref={lastMessage ? setRef : null} key={index} className={`my-1 d-flex flex-column ${message.fromMe ? 'align-self-end' : null}`}>
                            <div className={`rounded px-2 py-1 ${message.fromMe ? 'bg-primary text-white' : 'border align-self-start'}`}>
                                {message.text.includes('https') ? <img src={message.text} width="250" /> : message.text}
                            </div>
                            <div className={`text-muted small ${message.fromMe ? 'text-right' : ''}`}>
                                {message.fromMe ? 'You' : message.senderName}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group className='m-2'>
                    <InputGroup>
                        <Form.Control as='textarea' required value={text}
                            onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
                            style={{ height: '75px', resize: 'none' }} />
                        <InputGroup.Append className="d-flex">
                            <Uploadimage statefunction={sendImage} uid='imgMessage' tall='100%' wide='80px'  fsize='25px'/>
                            <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
                        </InputGroup.Append>
                    </InputGroup>

                </Form.Group>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**UploadImage.js**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {Form, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import styles from '../css/styles.module.css'
import LoaderIcon from '../css/loading-spin.svg'
import { useConversations } from '../contexts/ConversationsProvider';



export default function UploadImage({statefunction,uid,tall,wide,fsize}) {

    const { sendMessage, selectedConversation } = useConversations();

    var Imgur = function (options) {
        if (!this || !(this instanceof Imgur)) {
            return new Imgur(options);
        }

        if (!options) {
            options = {};
        }

        if (!options.clientid) {
            throw 'Provide a valid Client Id here: https://api.imgur.com/';
        }

        this.clientid = options.clientid;
        this.endpoint = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image';
        this.callback = options.callback || undefined;
        this.input = document.querySelectorAll('.'+uid);

        this.run();
    };

    Imgur.prototype = {
        createEls: function (name, props, text) {
            var el = document.createElement(name), p;
            for (p in props) {
                if (props.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    el[p] = props[p];
                }
            }
            if (text) {
                el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            }
            return el;
        },
        insertAfter: function (referenceNode, newNode) {
            referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
        },
        post: function (path, data, callback) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.open('POST', path, true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID ' + this.clientid);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                        var response = '';
                        try {
                            response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        } catch (err) {
                            response = this.responseText;
                        }
                        callback.call(window, response);
                    } else {
                        throw new Error(this.status + " - " + this.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhttp.send(data);
            xhttp = null;
        },
        createDragZone: function () {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.input, function (zone) {
                this.upload(zone);
            }.bind(this));
        },
        loading: function () {
            var div, table, img;

            div = this.createEls('div', {className: styles.loadingModal});
            table = this.createEls('table', {className: styles.loadingTable});
            img = this.createEls('img', {className: styles.loadingImage, src: LoaderIcon});

            div.appendChild(table);
            table.appendChild(img);
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        },
        
        matchFiles: function (file, zone) {

            if (file.type.match(/image/) && file.type !== 'image/svg+xml') {
                document.body.classList.add(styles.loading);

                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('image', file);

                this.post(this.endpoint, fd, function (data) {
                    document.body.classList.remove(styles.loading);
                    typeof this.callback === 'function' && this.callback.call(this, data);
                }.bind(this));
            }
        },
        upload: function (zone) {
            var events = ['dragenter', 'dragleave', 'dragover', 'drop'],
                file, target, i, len;

            zone.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'INPUT' && e.target.type === 'file') {
                    target = e.target.files;

                    for (i = 0, len = target.length; i < len; i += 1) {
                        file = target[i];
                        this.matchFiles(file, zone);
                    }
                }
            }.bind(this), false);

            
        },
        run: function () {
            var loadingModal = document.querySelector(styles.loadingModal);

            if (!loadingModal) {
                this.loading();
            }
            this.createDragZone();
        }
    };
    
    var feedback = function(res) {
        if (res.success === true) {
            var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
            statefunction(get_link)
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        new Imgur({
            clientid: '128d58ccad247be', //You can change this ClientID
            callback: feedback
        });
        
    }, [])
   
    
    return (
        <>
        
        <Form.File id="formcheck-api-regular" className={styles.inputWrapper}>
          <Button style={{borderRadius: '50%',height: tall,width: wide}}><i className="fa fa-camera" style={{fontSize: fsize}}></i></Button>
          <Form.File.Input className={`${uid} ${styles.input}`} />
        </Form.File>
        <div className="preview"></div>        
        </>
    )
}
```

The problem at hand is that whenever I send a text message using message box in **OpenConversation** component it successfully gets transmitted with the help of sendMessage function wrapped inside handleSubmit function in **OpenConversation**

[sending text message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZfLn.png)
[text message sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvyW.png)

But

Whenever I want to send URL of image returned by **UploadImage** Component to **OpenConversation** Component.
[selecting an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KssT0.png)

I get the following error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDxkA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the fact that you're initializing the Imgur API class inside a function and outside of a `useEffect` or passed param it's being called on each render therefor your references to the API are getting recalculated each update (AKA immediately!)

You should probably initiate the Imgur API class in another module and use it as an import!

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work. Moved all imgur API code to separate file, imported it in Uploadimage component but still getting same error. It works when I include it directly in Openconversation.js without using Uploadimage Component. I think this is occurring because the sendMessage function is being retrieved in OpenConversation through Context API & not in Uploadimage Component.  I can definitely work around this & make it work through some other approach but here I really want to understand the root cause of this particular issue.